# College homework using JavaScript, creating a JS Bin thing

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the numbers in the blocks to increase by 1 every time they are bumped, without the letters in the box changing. Before, I was able to get the numbers to increase by 1, but the words changed into "NaN" when they were bumped, and I did not want that.

I have tried various variations of the code/instruction, but nothing seems to work. Link is included below.

http://jsbin.com/yaqidejuho/1/

Comment: Consider putting relevant bits of code in the question, for example your `impact` function and the fact you're using gravityscript / `throw.js`, along with an example of the node that doesn't work as expected. This will help you get more answers. Furthermore, always check what your browser is telling you before you ask questions, sometimes it's an easy fix!

Comment: this is the code i am using. thanks a lot for your help.
<script type="text/javascript">
  function impact(object1, object2){

  if (isNaN(parseInt(object1) == false) {

    object1.innerHTML = parseInt(object1.innerHTML) +1;

  }

  if (isNaN(parseInt(object2) == false) {

    object2.innerHTML = parseInt(object2.innerHTML) +1;

  }
}
</script>
  
<span class="grav" style="background-color:red;font-size:30pt;">00</span>
<span class="grav" style="background-color:yellow;font-size:30pt;">00</span>
<span class="grav" style="background-color:cyan;font-size:30pt;">00</span>

Comment: @darknight You should edit the question to include relevant snippets. Most people won't read the comments...

Answer (score 1):

Look at your console, you're getting

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

This is because you've not closed all of your parenthesis in your `if` conditions. Fixing this error will allow your script to run.

The first step of debugging *JavaScript* should always be *"does my console tell me anything?"*

---

Next, rather than testing against *NaN*, consider adding a testable attribute, or making your test it's own method, for example

```
function isInt(str) {
    return /^-?\d+$/.test(str);
}
```

Now your `if` can be simplified down

```
if (isInt(object1.innerHTML))
    object1.innerHTML = +object1.innerHTML + 1;
if (isInt(object2.innerHTML))
    object2.innerHTML = +object2.innerHTML + 1;
```

---

There seems to be additional problems with your code as your *HTML* contains two `<body>` elements, which is invalid. This won't prevent the document from loading, but can cause unexpected results so you may want to make your *HMTL* valid at the same time.

Comment: when i got rid of the 2nd body, the entire back ground went away. and idk how to make a testable attribute, this is my 1st CS class. and when i inputted the new if statement, the blocks still didn't increase by 1 when bounce against other things. wtf, fml. i am so confused, what am i doing wrong?